# How to use background segmentation with cameraTexture in spark ar?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

When I add rectangle with background material I add camera texture, but it covers all face meshes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the render-order of your face mesh in the Advanced Render Options of the mesh material you're using, so that it gets rendered on top of the rectangle. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

New versions(Currently V. 102) of Spark AR Studio have the background template on the welcome screen but to answer this question and for using it in a project such as above since you can't import the template;

1. Click on Camera, then on the + sign on Texture Extraction and also on Person Segmentation
   [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbHCv.png)
2. Create another rectangle and new material for this rectangle
3. Click on the material you've just created and for texture, choose camera texture.
4. Check the alpha box and choose the person segmentation texture. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjIf1.png)
   Have the face masks as children of this rectangle that is the foreground.

[More on Background Segmentation](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/articles/people-tracking/background-segmentation/)